# Expectation Value of Randomly Sent Letters

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I have the problem where $n$ distinct letters are written for $n$ people and each letter is randomly mailed to one of these $n$ people.  All mailing are distinct.  Let $X$ denote the number of letters sent to the correct recipient.  What is the size of the sample space and what is the expected value?

My work thus far has the sample size at $n!$ with an expected value of $E(X) = \dfrac1n + \dfrac2{n^2} + \ldots + \dfrac{n}{n^n}$.  Does this look correct?

Comment: Presumably you're considering each of those terms $\frac1{n^i}$ as the probability $E_i$ that $i$ letters are sent to the correct recipient; how are you coming up with that value?  (A big hint: what is the probability that $n-1$ letters are sent to the correct recipients?)

Comment: A much easier way of modeling the problem to get the expected value: what is the probability $P_i$ that that $i$'th recipient gets the correct letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you’re looking for is the expected number of fixed points of a randomly chosen permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $X_k$ be the random variable that is $1$ if $k$ is a fixed point of the permutation and $0$ otherwise, and let $Y=X_1+\ldots+X_n$. Then $Y$ is the number of fixed points of the permutation, and

$$\Bbb E[Y]=\sum_{k=1}^n\Bbb E[X_k]$$

by [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). The expectations $\Bbb E[X_k]$ are easy to calculate:

$$\Bbb E[X_k]=\frac{m_k}{n!}\;,$$

where $m_k$ is the number of permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ fixing $k$; $m_k=\;$?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the sample space is $n!$; assign an arbitrary numbering to the letters ; then the first letter can be sent to any of n people; the second one to $(n-1)$ people, so that all letters can be sent in $n!$ ways.

If n is large enough, then you consider the number of derangements :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangements; if n is large-enough, the probability that no one received the correct letter approaches $1/e$. So you can work
the cases by assuming you have n=1 letter correctly-sent and then a derangement of (n-1) letters, then n=2 letters correctly sent in nC2 ways, and a derangement on the remaining ones, etc.